# IE compatibility errors- CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I know this is a broad question, but I was developing a portfolio site just something to mess around with, and I'm having compatibility errors in Internet Explorer.... Imagine that. The **errors are located in the **flipcard.css** and **flipcard.js** files**. So, basically all browsers, but IE will render the "live tiles" I have made correctly. However, in IE, they make my pictures display upside down, etc.

1. Is my CSS not supported?
2. Is my javascript not checking if IE is viewing correctly?

I know this isn't a typical question, but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The site - [Here](http://www.jdbechtold.com)

Comment: A question at SO should include, in the question itself, code for reproducing the issue. In particular, a link to a live site is definitely not enough – the question becomes useless to future visitors as soon as the problem has been fixed on the live site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ax2Mc/71/

Comment: I'm looking at your site right now in IE10 and I don't see pictures displayed upside down, sorry. In fact, the similarity between how it looks in IE and in Mozilla is striking.

Comment: Answered.. And i posted code to try to help others with the issue ... Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I wish that I could claim it but all ive done is modified it. The original creator is named Maroslaw i believe.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the comments and my own code ive found a solution that i will get working shortly. 
@ jukka Korpela - i understand and will describe briefly. 
@ Mr Lister - Thanks for Your time and review.. The issue was with ie11

So my problem was css transition compatibility or javascript fallback support for IE.

My fallback support did not correctly handle IE 11.

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
    // Returns the version of Windows Internet Explorer or a -1 if not
    {
       var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
       if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
       {
          var ua = navigator.userAgent;
          var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
          if (re.exec(ua) != null)
             rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
       }
       return rv;
    }

    if( getInternetExplorerVersion() != -1 ){ //IF IS IE
        fallback = true;
    }
```

Comment: As you have found, "MSIE" no longer features in the user agent string of Internet Explorer 11, and most likely subsequent versions after that. I am compelled to ask though, why are you detecting Internet Explorer and not features? Style properties can easily be detected using JavaScript, and Internet Explorer has supported transitions since version 10. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772284(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For more information on feature detection see http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html and the excellent article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475813.aspx